# Proof of whether endpoints are local extrema

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Was wondering whether anyone would be able to prove the following statement if it is correct, or if not, then provide a counter example.

Consider a differentiable function f on a finite closed interval [a, b]. The endpoints a and b are local extrema of the function.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x):=x^2\sin(1/x)$ if $x \ne 0$ and $f(0):=0$. Then $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$ (prove this !), but in $0$ there is no local extremum.

Comment: Let $x_n=\frac{2}{(2n+1) \pi}$. Then $f(x_n)=(-1)^{n+1}x_n^2$. Therefore: in each neighborhood of $0$, the function  $f$ attains values $> 0=f(0)$  and values $< 0=f(0)$

Comment: Take $a=0$ and $b=1$

Answer (score 1):

The end points could be as absolute max/min points but they (assuming the function has definite values at them) can not be as local extremes. As usual, at the local points, we don't have a definite neighborhood around. And that's why they have defects to be local ones. Consider the restricted function $$f(x)=\sin(x),~~x\in [0,\pi/2]$$ $x=0$ is just a minimum endpoint extreme.